# Node.js server is breaking without any error

Tags: node.js

I am using edge module (https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) to read from a sql database. Function is as follows:

```
function getBetweenRows(cb) {
    //console.log("lastcheckedID inside function ", lastCheckedID);
    //console.log("lastinsertID inside function ", lastInsertID);
    console.log("here 2");
    var query = {
        connectionString: "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=db-name;Integrated Security=True",
        //source: "SELECT * FROM CustomerMaster WHERE CustomerID BETWEEN '" + lastCheckedID + "' AND '" + lastInsertID + "';"
                    source: "SELECT * FROM CustomerMaster WHERE CustomerID BETWEEN '2965' AND '2972';"
    };

    console.log("query is ", query.source);
    console.log("here 3");
    var getRows = edge.func('sql', query);
    console.log("here 4");
    getRows(null, function(error, result) {
    console.log("here 5");
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            throw error;
            log.error({rows:error});

        }
        rows = result;
        log.info({rows:rows});
        console.log(rows);
    console.log("here 6");

        cb(rows);
    });
}
```

Funny thing is this code is working perfectly on some other systems. But on this particular system, it prints till `here 4` and then the server breaks. It doesn't show any error whatsoever. How do I find out what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't know from what is posted what is happening diferently on diferent systems but if you want to debug and find the step by step diferences on the two systems, use the node debugger:

http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

It's worth getting to know.

Also, I have noticed occasional issues which I cannot yet explain, when throwing errors.  Try commenting out the throw line on the offending system (an maybe the log.js call as well.)  If this fixes the issue, you know it is something to do with the errors.

Let me know what you find.